# Whats a better way to write this function. Its gets a remote file and copys it localy, in php

Tags: php, windows, linux, http, winapi

So yea, im working on a windows system and while this works locally, know it will break on other peoples servers.  Whats a cross platform way to do the same as this

```
function fetch($get,$put){
    file_put_contents($put,file_get_contents($get));
}
```

Comment: Why will it break on other's people servers? as long as the fopen wrappers are enabled the above will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be the solution using simple file operations:

```
<?php
$file = "http://www.domain.com/thisisthefileiwant.zip";
$hostfile = fopen($file, 'r');
$fh = fopen("thisisthenameofthefileiwantafterdownloading.zip", 'w');

while (!feof($hostfile)) {
    $output = fread($hostfile, 8192);
    fwrite($fh, $output);
}

fclose($hostfile);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Ensure your directory has write permissions enabled. (CHMOD)

Therefore, a replacement for your fetch($get, $put) would be:

```
function fetch($get, $put) {    
    $hostfile = fopen($get, 'r');
    $fh = fopen($put, 'w');

    while (!feof($hostfile)) {
        $output = fread($hostfile, 8192);
        fwrite($fh, $output);
    }

    fclose($hostfile);
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Hope it helped! =)

---

Cheers, 
KrX

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why that would fail unless the other computer is on PHP4. What you would need to do to make that **backwards** compatible is add functionality to provide replacements for file_get_contents & file_put_contents:

```
if(version_compare(phpversion(),'5','<')) {
    function file_get_contents($file) {
        // mimick functionality here
    }    
    function file_put_contents($file,$data) {
        // mimick functionality here
    }
}
```

Comment: if it is a v4 vs v5 issue, http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat has file_put_contents() (file_get_contents is in v4.3+)

Answer (score 0):

Shawn's answer is absolute correct, the only thing is that you need to make sure your $put varialable is a valid path on either the Windows Server on the Unix server.

Answer (score 0):

well when i read your question I understood you wanted to bring a file from a remote server to your server locally, this can be done with the FTP extension from php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fget.php

if this is not what you intent I believe what shawn says is correct

else tell me in the comments and i'll help you more

Answer (score 0):

If the fopen wrappers are not enabled, the curl extension could be: http://php.net/curl